# can I nest insert t-sql inside an update t-sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-merge

Is it possible to nest an insert statement inside of an update statement?

**Background**:

I am using the `merge` clause for the very first time to transform some data. that is, I have a single source table with many columns but need to, for lack if a better word, *transform* to a more structured model/schema; Similar to that of a `BI` model. I am also inexperienced in BI modelling as well (just started reading about it less than a month now). Any help would be greatly 
appreciated.

I will gladly provide any other information that may be needed to assist.

**Error:**

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 47
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 48
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

These are thrown at the point where I try to do the *insert into tertiary.WEBADDRESS* lines.

**Code:**

```
--Transform operation
--web address dimension insert
use UniversityUS
merge tertiary.INSTITUTION as target
using(
        select UNITID,
             INSTNM,
             ADDR,
             CITY,
             STABBR,
             ZIP,
             OBEREG,
             WEBADDR,
             ADMINURL,
             FAIDURL,
             APPLURL,
             HLOFFER,
             GENTELE,
             LOCALE,
             CARNEGIE,
             FAXTELE,
             IALIAS,
             F1SYSNAM,
             COUNTYNM,
             LONGITUD,
             LATITUDE
             --geography::Point(LATITUDE,LONGITUD,4326)) as [LOCATION]
        from staging.secondary_university
        where closedat = -2
    ) as source
on ( source.UNITID = target.ROWSOURCECONTROLID )
when not matched by target then

        --this would represent my fact table
        insert (INSTNM,IALIAS,GENTELE,F1SYSNAM,ROWSOURCECONTROLID)
        values (source.INSTNM,source.IALIAS,source.GENTELE,source.F1SYSNAM,source.UNITID)       

when matched then

        update set target._WEBADDRID = 
        (
            select wa.wid
            from
            (
                --this would represent one of my many dimension tables
                --if i comment the next two lines it works
                --but i need to know how will these be updated.
                insert into tertiary.WEBADDRESS 
                values(source.WEBADDR,source.ADMINURL,source.FAIDURL,source.APPLURL)

                select scope_identity() as wid
            )wa 
        )

when not matched by source then
    delete
output $action;
```

Comment: I strongly recommend [reading this article before you fall too in love with `MERGE`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - here I was struggling to find out how to do the transforms (new to BI) now this? haha....Am glad u pointed this out to me early. One thing I have noticed is that it did not insert all the rows into the new table. am not exactly sure of the problem, but will, in the mean time look at separating the statements. thnx.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is kind of an old question, but it's an interesting one so I'll answer as best I can for anyone who might stumble across it in researching their own curiosities.

I'll start by saying that this is probably bad practice. By attempting to nest statements like this, you're risking unreadable code and it wouldn't be overly surprising to me if some concurrency issues came up. If you're completely sold on this, though, you could probably accomplish something like it with a stored procedure. But again, something that side-effects unclearly like that will probably be unreadable. You might also look into the `OUTPUT` clause of that insert. I'm not sure, but it makes sense that you'd be able to add in an `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` (or whatever your identity column is named) and run your select against that, rather than utilizing an insert followed by a select. Again, I'm not sure if that would work. But it sounds reasonable.

That all said, as it looks like Aaron alluded to in his comment, it would be better to separate this out into a few separate operations. I'm personally okay with `MERGE`, I've used it and it has yet to cause me any of the problems warned of in that post, although they could also be old news by now since we are a few versions in. But I would at least advise that you pull your insert out into a separate, even transaction-sharing, statement:

```
INSERT INTO tertiary.WEBADDRESS 
SELECT WEBADDR, ADMINURL, FAIDURL, APPLURL
    FROM staging.secondary_university
    WHERE closedat = -2 AND
          EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM tertiary.INSTITUTION
                  WHERE tertiary.Institution.ROWSOURCECONTROLID = staging.secondary_university.UNITID)
```

Then you could easily modify your `WHEN MATCHED` clause to fetch the appropriate identity value given whatever keys you need to establish uniqueness.

```
 ...
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET target._WEBADDRID = (SELECT TOP 1 [whatever_your_ID_column_is]
                                      FROM staging.secondary_university
                                      WHERE staging.secondary_university.WebAddr = source.WebAddr AND
                                            staging.secondary_university.ADMINURL = source.ADMINURL AND
                                            staging.secondary_university.FAIDURL = source.FAIDURL AND
                                            staging.secondary_university.APPLURL = source.APPLURL)
 ...
```